# Get Data From Last 48 Hours

Tags: sql-server, powerpivot

I'm using PowerPivot with an SQL Server database and I'm working with a specific table that includes a DateTime column. I'd like to select the data from the table where that DateTime is within the last 48 hours. I'm using a query currently and hoping to achieve something like

`... WHERE DT > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL +2 DAY)`

I'm getting a syntax error at `DAY` in this particular way. Is this the best way to do it? If so, what's wrong with how I've written it? If not, what's a better way?

Comment: You have tagged your question with `Sql-server` tag and you are using Mysql function `DATE_SUB` in your where clause ??? are you working on Mysql or Sql-server ???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Sql-Server**

```
WHERE DateTimeColumn >= DATEADD(HOUR, -48, GETDATE())
```

**Mysql**

```
WHERE DateTimeColumn > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR)
```

Comment: Looks like I didn't properly make sure the last answer I reviewed was SQL Server instead of MySQL. Thanks!

Comment: Not use `GETDATE()`, DateTime parameter ?