# How to delete a record automatically in sql and php after 2 days?

Tags: php, sql

I want to automatically delete a record from my database sql after 2 days of inserting the record. I am currently developing a simple reservation. How can I achieve this??

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18181618/2460773

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Data From Last 48 Hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586548/get-data-from-last-48-hours)

Comment: You need to be more clear. Does the record contain create date. If so then you need a trigger

Comment: Im creating a simple reservation. And what I want is to delete the record automatically after 2 days. 
DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),thatColumn) < -1

Comment: Where do i put this code?

Comment: @DaveEspada: Put it in an event. Defne one in your SQL engine that runs every day

Answer (score 0):

Add an event to your table that runs once every day and deletes those entries. You need to have a `date` column though to recognize these records.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using some sort of timestamp on insert then you can run a scheduled job that checks the age of the record with `datediff` and then deletes the record if `datediff = 2` days

Comment: I want to Automatically delete a record from the database without a command from the user.. is this code right?
DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),thatColumn) < -1
and where do I put it?

Comment: I would do: Datediff(Day,thatColumn, GetDate()) >= 2 but yes that will work. You need to create a job for it. If you're in SQL Server go into SQL Server Agent and create a new job, then assign a schedule to that job. If you let me know what DBMS you're using I can try help futher